# How to iterate through vector passed as pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

My question is in comment in below code.

```
void printVec(std::vector<int> *myVec) {

 // How to do such looping not to dereference pointer
 for (int i = 0; i < myVec->size(); i++) {
   std::cout << myVec->[i] << " ";
 }
}
```

Comment: You have to dereference the pointer.

Comment: Instead of passing as a pointer, pass it by reference. Also, use range-based for loops if you have C++11.

Comment: try `myVec->at(i)`.

Comment: To use the operator[]  use`(*myvec)[i]`

Comment: Or `myVec->operator[](i)`

Comment: `operator->` is also dereferencing, in case you were under the impression that it is not.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I'd say even passing a `const&` incurs in dereference under the hood in this circumstance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either

Pass the argument by `const` reference:

```
void printVec(const std::vector<int>& vec) {
  for (const auto& value : vec)
    ..
}
```

Use iterators:

```
void printVec(td::vector<int>* vec) {
  for (auto it = vec->begin(); it != vec->end(); ++it)
    ..
}
```

Use `at` (performance cost for bound check):

```
vec->at(i);
```

Invoke `operator[]` directly:

```
vec->operator[](i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass by reference:

```
void printVec(std::vector<int> & myVec) {

 // How to do such looping not to dereference pointer
 for (int i = 0; i < myVec.size(); i++) {
   std::cout << myVec[i] << " ";
 }
}
```

Also it's better to use range based for loops (C++11):

```
void printVec(std::vector<int> & myVec) {

 // How to do such looping not to dereference pointer
 for (auto i : myVec) {
   std::cout << i << " ";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your pointer to a reference and proceed from there:

```
void printVec(std::vector<int> *myVec) {
    std::vector<int>& vec = *myVec;
    // How to do such looping not to dereference pointer
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec->size(); i++) {
      std::cout << vec[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand I think you are trying to pass it like an array of ints, something like this might work

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void printVec(int* i, int n)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        std::cout << i[j] << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a;
    a.push_back(5);
    a.push_back(4);
    a.push_back(3);
    a.push_back(2);
    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(0);
    printVec(&a[0], a.size());
    return 0;
}
```